# How to control routes with multiple interfaces having static ip addresses

Tags: networking, nginx

I am making a Ubuntu LTS 16.04.2 LTS server box.
This server has 3 interfaces, Public (ETH0), Private (ETH1), Management (ETH2).
This server has 3 static IP addresses.

The default route changes sometimes from boot to boot between the configured interfaces.  I want to Ubuntu to use the default route I configure, not what it thinks it wants to use.  Where is it getting the default route anyway?

Typically I put this in the /etc/network/interfaces config, but I am not used to working in a configuration with multiple interfaces.   I have UP ROUTE..  commands, sometimes they are set, sometimes not.    They are at the end of the config, but tried moving them to under the interface config with no luck.

I have tried POST-UP, same results.
I have tried putting it in rc.local but that doesnt work.
Sometimes routes appear in netstat -r, route, route -n, whatever command you want to use, other times they do not.    It seems to depend on the default route the box selects on boot up.

How do I tell Ubuntu NOT to create any routes at all but use this table I supply... ?   Basically, send 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 out Eth0  and static route Eth2, for example   route 10.100.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth2

I can do this all manually, but want it persistent and consistent between reboots.

What does resolv.conf have to do with anything here?

Thank you.

Comment: What you want to do? You server can have only one default route in time. I guess that you only need default route on your "public" interface `eth0`? If you do not need trough `eth1` access any other resources then on "private" network, you do not need default route on that interface. That mean if you have ip: 10.10.10.1/24 and you will access only 10.10.10.xxx host with that network you do not need to send packet to default gateway.

Comment: Hi, I only want 1 default route, as you say "public" Eth0.

Comment: When I reboot, sometimes it picks ETH0 as the default route, sometimes it picks ETH1 as the default route.   I want it to be consistent by always picking ETH0 as the default.

Comment: Example, if I ping  the IP address assigned to ETH0 and ping the IP address of ETH1, ping replies when things are working correctly.

Comment: I have a bad habbit of hitting return, sorry for all the messages -

Comment: Example, if I ping the IP address assigned to ETH0 and ping the IP address of ETH1, ping replies when things are working correctly   -  reboot the machine and maybe only ETH0 or ETH1 or both will work.  Look at route table and the default route changes from Eth0 or Eth1, the only one that returns pings.    Perhaps I am giving too much detail, I just want Ubuntu to pick ETH0 ALWAYS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start

Topology

```
---------
|  pc1  |--- 192.168.0.10------192.168.0.250/eth1--|---------|
---------                Private                   |         |
                                                   | server  |--172.20.20.20/eth0
---------                                          |         |        Public
|  pc2  |--- 192.168.1.10------192.168.1.250/eth2--|---------|
---------               Management
```

Like I say, if your server do not need communicate through `eth1` except machines from `192.168.0.0/24` network and if do not need to communicate through `eth2` except machines from `192.168.1.0/24` network you do not need gateways on this interfaces. Configuration well be

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.20.20.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.20.20.1


auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.0.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
        address 192.168.2.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

To add more route to some interface

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.20.20.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.20.20.1


auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.0.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        up route add -net 192.168.18.0/24 dev eth1
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
        address 192.168.2.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Or if you need gateways on interfaces you can add metric. Interface with less metric have priority

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.20.20.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.20.20.1

auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.0.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        metric 400
        up route add -net 192.168.18.0/24 dev eth1

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
        address 192.168.2.250
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.2.1
        metric 800
```

This are example of configuration. Change with your ip net's, metric, routes per interfaces ....

When you do configuration save `/etc/network/interfaces`, restart network

```
sudo service networking restart
```

or you can restart `server`

Comment: Yes, exactly.  My bad, I guess I am trying to add 2 gateways.  I only need the internet facing one and will add static routes to the rest.  Does it matter where I place the up route statements (can they be at the end?  Is there any difference in specifying them in the particular interface?   I also seen post-up and up,  why?   Thank you for your answer and detail.  Marked as answer.

Comment: when you put route into interface config that route will be up when interface go up. When you put post-up route at the end of config that route will be triggered regardless of the state of interface.

Comment: Is post correct? It appears to have IPs not in the topology at the top? eth2 in the topology has .1 as the 3rd octet, in the write up it has .2?