# If I have bound two IP address on one NIC, So How can I use both at same time ? Or can I switch to each other?

Tags: 16.04, ip, bind, nic

If I have bound two ip address on same NIC in ubuntu 16.04. So how can I use both either at same time or by switching to each other ?

Comment: For clarification, you already have two IP addresses configured on a single NIC, correct? And your question is how to use them? If they're separate IP addresses, they will behave as separate IP addresses. If this is not your question, you might want to provide an example of what you're ultimately trying to do. If it is, perhaps [this discussion will help](https://askubuntu.com/q/921654/32664).

Comment: Yes, I have two IPs on single NIC. My question is when I use second ip (Binding) on this NIC then I can see it by typing ip address or ifconfig command and also I can ping it. But how can system use it like login to Cyberoam client that only allow a specific IP address.