# How to specify a static route among three interfaces

Tags: networking, routing

I have this setup:

```
                                       10.5.128.150
Ubuntu                              Ubuntu eth2 <------>   server (10.5.128.154)
client  eth1     <---->    eth1     Router eth3 <------>
    10.5.129.179       10.5.129.39       10.5.130.201
```

Thus the Ubuntu router is managing three domains:

- 10.5.129.0/24 : This is where the client lives
- 10.5.128.0/24 : Governed by eth2 and connects to the server.
- 10.5.130.0/24 : Governed by eth3

Following the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/168037/347674, I've configured the client to use the router as the gateway for 10.5.128.0/24 traffic.

Here's the route table on the router:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
....
10.5.128.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
10.5.129.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.5.130.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
```

This all looks fine to me, but when I try to ping that server from the client, I get no reply:

```
# ping -n -I eth1 10.5.128.154                                                                                                                                  
PING 10.5.128.154 (10.5.128.154) from 10.5.129.179 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
```

The router shows the ping traffic correctly coming into the router's eth1:

```
# tcpdump -n -i eth1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:20:17.428153 IP 10.5.129.179 > 10.5.128.154: ICMP echo request, id 909, seq 170, length 64
15:20:17.618104 IP 10.5.129.179 > 10.5.128.154: ICMP echo request, id 874, seq 2534, length 64
15:20:18.427959 IP 10.5.129.179 > 10.5.128.154: ICMP echo request, id 909, seq 171, length 64
```

But the ping blackholes on the router. It never goes out the eth2 interface like I'd expect it to:

```
# tcpdump -n -i eth2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

(It's empty.)

In fact it's not going anywhere:

```
# tcpdump -n -i any icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
15:31:53.138046 IP 10.5.129.179 > 10.5.128.154: ICMP echo request, id 874, seq 3224, length 64
15:31:54.145980 IP 10.5.129.179 > 10.5.128.154: ICMP echo request, id 874, seq 3225, length 64
15:31:55.154033 IP 10.5.129.179 > 10.5.128.154: ICMP echo request, id 874, seq 3226, length 64
```

Shouldn't the ping's requests egress on eth2 per its route table? Or is there something else I need to configure on the Ubuntu router to get the packets to egress from eth2?

Comment: You might have more luck posting this on https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://serverfault.com

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/921862/231142 help by chance?